# back up my ubuntu partition for quick restore

Tags: backup

I have recently set up my laptop for my ubuntu environment. Now that it's the way that I want it, I want to back it up so if something happens, I can wipe the hard drive, re-install Ubuntu from the original CD, then restore from backup to put everything back the way it is.

So here's the list of folders in my root directory of my hard drive.

```
bin    dev   initrd.img      lib32       media  proc  sbin     sys  var
boot   etc   initrd.img.old  lib64       mnt    root  selinux  tmp  vmlinuz
cdrom  home  lib             lost+found  opt    run   srv      usr  vmlinuz.old
```

I'm thinking the things I need to backup are:

```
bin
boot
etc
home
initrd.img
lib
lib32
lib64
opt--this is where I install my development tools like eclipse and tomcat
sbin
usr
vmlinuz
```

Anything else?

Comment: dupe question - http://askubuntu.com/q/83927/46312

Comment: I'd just backup everything as it is (i.e. the whole partition). You're trying to save up on some space that is minuscule in relation to other folders: http://pastebin.com/M9DQmYQB - In addition to that, I would use a program like deja backup tool to backup regularly my home folder.

Comment: I thought the deja backup was the way to go too, till I tried it.  First it would not backup all files claiming some were inaccessable.  Then when run as admin it could not find my usb hard drive to even get started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clonezilla does a great job... http://clonezilla.org/

Answer (score 1):

I would image it. Look here for all the info you need: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DriveImaging

Sysrescuecd and others have tools as well. fsarchiver is one that comes to mind.